# Oracle Apex Dynamic actions in tabular form

Tags: dynamic, resources, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I am developing an app that captures the every day resource utilization of a person in a team.

I completed every thing and stuck up at a point i.e

Please find the below link for the image (I cant upload image here as I am a new user)

http://s17.postimg.org/qgh6559rj/image.jpg

As shown in the above image I created a Tabular form for this where month is a drop down list and year is a text box, the days `1,2,3,....31` are text boxes to capture utilized time.

My requirement is to make the days greyed out and lock (not to allow the user to enter data) for the days which are not in that month.

```
ex: when Month : Feb then 29,30,31 : greyed out and locked
```

I have searched in many websites for the solution, But I couldn't get one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your explanations. Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: Why disable? Why not show in the first place? This would either be driven by the (unsupplied) SQL source of your tabular form or could be driven by a condition on the last few columns.

Comment: Have you thought about using a calendar instead of trying to handle this kind of validation yourself?

Comment: Dimitry -  please find the link http://s17.postimg.org/qgh6559rj/image.jpg

-thanks

Comment: Hello Every one please help me

Comment: Question also present in OTN forum, with more info: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3698459

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aditya,
I tried to solve this problem.I created similar tabular form having colmns like day1,day2...Day29,Day30,Day31.Here I have focused on only day29,Day30,Day31 as because  only these columns will get affect on change of year. Rather than dynamic action I have called JavaScript function hideShow() on change of year [image]

Following is code for hideShow where as f04,f05,f06 are day29,day30,day31.
In this function I also added possibility of leap year

```
function hideShow(pThis)
{

   var month=$(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f02"]').val();
   var year=$(pThis).val();

    if (Boolean(parseInt(year) % 4 == 0)&&Boolean(parseInt(year) % 100 != 0)||Boolean(parseInt(year) % 400 == 0)) {
       if (month.trim()=='FEB') {
        $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f05"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f06"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }

     } 
     else {
        if (month.trim()=='FEB') {
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f04"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f05"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f06"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
     }

       if(month.trim()=='APR') {
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f06"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
       }
       else if(month.trim()=='JUN') {
          $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f06"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
       }
       else if(month.trim()=='SEP') { 
          $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f06"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
       }
       else if(month.trim()=='JAN'||month.trim()=='MAR'||month.trim()=='MAY'||month.trim()=='JUL'||month.trim()=='AUG') {
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f04"]').attr("disabled",false);
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f05"]').attr("disabled",false);
         $(pThis).closest('tr').find('[name="f06"]').attr("disabled",false);

       }
 }
```

Here I only worked with disable/enable, similarly it is also possible to apply css runtime, Hope this code will help you...